# Error: Cannot find module 'html' with /:id

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I recently had a problem with express while rendering html pages.
I have the following organization for my app :

`app/
   server.js
   views/
        index.html
        dashboard.html
        containers/
                 show.html
......`

In server.js I declared the following route :

```
app.configure(function(){
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/views')));
});

app.get('/containers/:id',function(req,res){
   console.log("Inspect container");
   res.render('/views/containers/show.html');
});
```

And in dashboard.html I have a link that looks like this :

```
<a href="/containers/'+data[i].Id+'">Test</a>
```

But when I try to access the following link i get this error :

`Error: Cannot find module 'html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at new View (/root/HarborJS/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:43:49)
    at Function.app.render (/root/HarborJS/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:488:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/root/HarborJS/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:759:7)
    at io.sockets.on.socket.on.exec.user (/root/HarborJS/server.js:32:7)
    at callbacks (/root/HarborJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/root/HarborJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)`

I really don't know what to do at this point. Tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `res.render` for rendering templates, but you are telling it to render a basic HTML file and it doesn't know what to do with that since `html` is not a template language. What are you trying to achieve with `'+data[i].Id+'`? What is `data`?

Comment: data[i].Id is just an Id I get from socket.io nothing special here. So what should I do ? Shall I switch to jade  immediately in order to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`res.render` is used for dynamically generating the page HTML server-side for each request. You have passed it the path to an HTML file, but HTML is not a templating language, so it is throwing an error.

If you do not have any template logic in `show.html` then you should just send the file back without using a template engine, e.g.

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/containers/show.html');
```

If you do have things that need to be rendered server-side, then you should pick a templating engine, of which there are many, and then rename the files to have a template extension.

Comment: Thank you, indeed what you said is completely logic I should have figured out that by myself by reading some doc.

Comment: now its darn clear.. what 'render' and 'sendFile' methods are supposed to do... thanks mate